# How to convert matrix to a keras compatible image?

Tags: python, python-3.x, keras

What I want to do is to convert somthing like this matrix (a 2D list in python)

0 0 0

1 1 1

0 0 0

to an image like this

black black black

white white white

black black black

which will be compatible with keras's convolutional layer?

p.s.

I lack the knowledge of the actual data structure of an "image" used by keras, and therefore I am stuck in a rut. If possible, it would be nice if anyone could also tell me what kind of data structure an image is. My current guess is a 3 dimensional array of width, height, and RGB values, or 2 dimensional array for a monochrome image. However, I am not sure if it's a value from 0 to 1, or 0 to 255. I also suspect that the value has to be in type "float32" but I am not sure what to do with that facts.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Keras is numeric, so, `0` and `1` are perfect for the task, you don't have to do anything else, except for observing the required `input_shape` of the first layer.

It's not a big problem if you use 0 to 255 either, but the standard is to work with 0 to 1. It's important that your outputs match the last 'activation' you use. (Example: 'sigmoid' activation will give outputs between 0 and 1).

**Convolutional layers input shape:**

For giving data as input for a convolutional layer, you must shape the data like this:

```
(NumberOfImages, Width, Heigth, channels) #W and H may be inverted, but it doesn't matter much as long as they will not be swapped along the model.
```

Channels stand for images with red, green, blue channels, for instance. Some images may have 4 channels. Black and white images have one channel.

**What kind of data strucure an image is?**

It will depend a lot on which library you use to load your images. 
If you have numpy arrays, just work with numbers from 0 to 1 as before.

When using `pillow` (an image library), it will return things from 0 to 255, all you have to do is create a numpy array from it and divide it by 255.

```
from PIL import Image
import numpy as np

im = Image.open(filename)
im = im.resize(size,Image.LANCZOS) #if your images are not already the size you want    
im = np.asarray(im)/255
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! I got my code working now! I would also like to be able to display those matrix as a rendered image (and not a 0 and 1 being frantically printed onto my console). I would simply have to convert an array of shape (width, height, channel) into values between 0 and 255 yes?

Comment: With `matplotlib` you could plot numpy arrays from 0 to 1, no problem. There might be many other libraries for plotting numpy arrays as images.